# Can't Access Webmin on GCE Instance on port 10000

Tags: webmin

I have a GCE Instance a Debian 1v CPU & 1.7GB. Then I followed the below tutorial and installed webmin on it.
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-15-04/

The installation went successfully. Then I Created a Firewall exception on using the UFW and allowed port 10000.

```
sudo ufw allow 10000/tcp
```

But I was not able to access Webmin through the browser.

**https://my-gce-instance-ip-address:10000**.

Then i created firewall exception using the Google Cloud Console. Again tried the url it didnt work.

Then i thought this might be because of webmin is https mode. So i open the /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf and changed ssl=0. After that i restarted the webmin.

```
/etc/init.d/webmin restart
```

Then I tried the the url with Http, still I can't access.

I tried below command and checked the output. Accordingly Webmin is correctly running and listening on port 10000.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :10000.
```

I can't seem to think what I am doing wrong. I have now spent several days on this without and solution in sight. Hope someone can kindly help me?

Comment: ok, i found out the solution my self. it was a firewall issue. I tried to access the port from a port checker utility but it always said that the port was closed. but as i said in my earlier post i opened the port in ufw as well as google cloud console. Here is the catch it's a problem with tags. it's like this We can create tags for each instance in google cloud platform. it seems tag is like an identifier for each instance. i created a tag called webmin for my instance. This is the same as creating a label for the instance. Then i add the tag/label to the firewall rule then it startedworking

Answer (score 0):

you need to allow port 10000 from iptables

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

this work for me
i'm using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

try this ... it's working for me

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

open both link in Browser

https://your-IP:10000
and
http://your-IP:10000

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any firewall configuration in the instance itself. All firewall configuration is done in the Google Cloud console.

The steps I typically follow, as you show to have figured out in your comment, are:

- Create the firewall rule, in it opening the particular port you need (`10000` in the case of Webmin) for ingress TCP traffic, accepting connections from some IP range (e.g. `0.0.0.0/0`), and specifying target tags to be later assigned to instances to which that rule shall apply.
- Add one of those tags to the "network tags" section of some particular instance.

This alone should work, opening the port for your instance in the firewall.

I was almost creating another question here on SO when yours was suggested as a possible duplicate. I had followed the steps above on my Webmin machine, and yet the machine refused to connect on port 10000. As I kept writing the question, I figured out my particular problem: in the firewall rule, in the source IP range filter, I set the single meta-address `0.0.0.0` instead of the range `0.0.0.0/0`. So, to anyone who has followed the steps above and still can't connect to their webmin installation, do check if your source range filter is correctly set.